# Learning a distribution when observing a OR between several classes

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, inference, discrete-data

I have a discrete categorical variable $X$ with values in $\{1,2,....m\}$, $m$ being rather small (say 10, 100...). I want to estimate the distribution of $X$: the histogram.

If my dataset was made of $n$ (say 1000,10000...) observations of $X$ things would be very easy:
$$p_i=\frac{\#i}{n}$$

Each line in my dataset is actually not a class but a disjunction of classes. For example a line says "$X$ is either 1 or 5 or 6".

To test the method, I'm working with a generated dataset this way: for each line:

- pickup a random $x$ according to the distribution
- pickup a random part $A$ of $\{1,2,....m\}$
- add the line $x\in A$ or $x\in\overline A$ depending on which is true

**Do you know how to estimate the distribution of $X$ in this case?**

So far, I've tried basic Bayesian inference with Dirichet prior, but it leads to nearly impossible computations (I still haven't tried MCMC). Maximum likelihood is also a possibility but it's not so easy.

Do you see a good idea or relate it to some known problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a special case of [Expectation Maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm).

Start by initializing $p$ as uniform.
Repeat until convergence:

- initialize counts (for each value) to 0
- for each line in the dataset like $\{1,5,6\}$, estimate the latent $X$ thanks to the current distribution $p$: add count $\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_5+p_6}$, $\frac{p_5}{p_1+p_5+p_6}$ , $\frac{p_6}{p_1+p_5+p_6}$ for 1, 5 and 6 respectively
- compute the new distribution based on these counts and assign it to $p$

The first two points are essentially the Expectation step: the log-likelihood being represented by the array of counts. The last point is the Maximization step.

I've tested an it works very well. You may regularize a bit by initializing counts to 1 instead of 0 which helps for small datasets.